# SAS SPDS table primary constraint unable to add

Tags: sas, sas-dis

I am trying to add primary constraint on a SAS SPDS table.

Error i am receivig is - 
1. ERROR: Engine SASSPDS does not support integrity constraint operations
2. ERROR: Requested function is not supported.

I am unable to proceed.
Query i have used -

1.

```
PROC DATASETS LIB=libname;
       MODIFY tablename;
       IC CREATE PK_IDENTPRODUKT= primary key (IDENTPRODUKT);
QUIT;
```

**** and also tried 
2.

```
proc sql;
alter table libname.tablename add constraint PK_IDENTPRODUKT primary key (IDENTPRODUKT);
quit;
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't support what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cherry_bueno Sounds like you have enough for an answer there!

Comment: @cherry_bueno - You are talking about "SPDE" and the question is about SPDS, please don't paste links blindly without knowing about the question and context.

Answer (score 0):

SPDS was created with ACID compliance and does support INDEX creation. Please refer to the link below which will be very helpful
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/spdsug/64018/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1ssxe4zp7vvijn1wkn1pdjrk891.htm